# Bash-like for loop in the Bourne and Korn shells?

Tags: for-loop, sh, ksh, portability

I need to read an input from the user (`N`) and execute the loop `N` times to perform a set of statements. In `bash`, I can use the following for-loop syntax:

```sh
read N 
for((i=0;i<$N;i++)) 
set of statements
```

However, I can't use that syntax in shells such as `sh` or `ksh`. What should I do, instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your script must be compatible with the Bourne shell (`sh`), be aware that the latter doesn't offer the numeric, "C-like" for-loop syntax (`for((i=0;i<$N;i++))`). However, you can use a `while` loop, instead.

Here is a POSIX-compliant approach, which works as expected with both `sh` and `ksh`:

```sh
read N

i=0                   # initialize counter
while [ $i -lt $N ]
do
  printf %s\\n "foo"  # statements ... 
  i=$((i+1))         # increment counter
done
```

Tests:

```
$ sh test.sh 
3
foo
foo
foo
$ ksh test.sh 
4
foo
foo
foo
foo
$ dash test.sh  # (dash is a minimalist, POSIX-compliant shell)
2
foo
foo
```

Comment: No need to use `expr`; `i=$((i+1))` is POSIX-compliant.